# Generating a random number returns java.util.Random@15db9742

Tags: java

I'm trying to generate a random number and remove it from an arraylist but it returns java.util.Random@15db9742, rather than a number.

My two constructors and the removal.

```
 public Randomlist(){
  this.alist = new ArrayList<E>();
  this.rand = new Random();

 }

 public Randomnlist(int seed) {
    this.alist = new ArrayList<E>();
    this.rand = new Random(seed);

}

public E randomnum(){
  Random x = this.rand;
  this.alist.remove(x);
  return (E)x;
}
```

It seems like its return maybe the memory location, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Read the documentatio of `Random` to see how you have to use it. What you see te the `toSting()` representation of this object.

Comment: You're looking at the `Random` object itself, which is actually something that generates random numbers. To get a random integer, e.g., look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt()

Answer (score 2):

`new Random()` returns a random number *generator*, which is a Java object (this is why you get `java.util.Random@15db9742` if you try to convert it to a string).  What you want is to get random numbers from it, using `this.rand.nextInt()` or `this.rand.nextFloat()` etc., depending on what kind of random number you want.

See [java.util.Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) on the API spec (linked version is Java 8).

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rand = new Random();

int  n = rand.nextInt(X) + 1;
```

// X is the maximum and the 1 is the minimum

Answer (score 0):

to get for example the next integer please do this.rand.nextInt(); nextInt() method will return a random integer

Answer (score 0):

That's the class name + @ + the object's hash code.

x should be whatever type of random you're trying to return.

```
public E randomnum(){
  E x = this.rand;
  this.alist.remove(x);
  return x;
}
```

in which case,

`Random rand = new Random(seed);
this.rand = rand.nextInt()`

Or double, or whatever you're wanting to use.